# Preparing for Internationalization of Asp.net MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization, globalization

I'm going to start a website which I know is going to be presented in multiple languages. However, for the first version we're only going to need the English version. Once the features are all working, we'll add the other languages.

Unfortunately since there are not enough enough features baked into Asp.Net Core, we have to use the Asp.Net MVC 5 for the website. My question has 2 parts:

1. Right now, which practice is considered the best approach for this? Using resource files and loading them in razor pages? Using a framework? Can we use the new localization and globalization features of Asp.Net MVC 6 somehow? Or is there a better alternative? I personally hate using the resource files. It adds too much clutter to the code.
2. Would you suggest just using plane text for now and then adding the Internationalization features to the website or start now and only add the translations?

Comment: Its depends. 
From my experience for SPA(Angular) I'm always going in this wway:

1) Creating resource files.
2) When User open website - I'm load all resource as Dictionary to javascript
3) On Page I write KEY from dictionary.
If user will change language - you just need replace dictionary in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I would use resource files, seems to be the easiest solution. You can also use a Database resource provider, so you have less clutter.

If you start with plain text, it will get more complicated and cumbersome to add the translations later. So I would not do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question though, would you suggest reading the localization info from the cookie/user settings or from the URL? Some websites use the URL to indicate the language for instance: http://somesite.com/en-US/controller/action

Comment: We have two approaches: For the public part of our side we use it inside the URL like you suggested. This makes a lot of sense, also from an SEO point of view. You also can get weird results if somebody sees an English page, forwards the URL to a friend and he gets a German page. And Google generally does not like it if he gets potential different results for the same URL.
For the private (logged in) part, we use the users settings.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Smart internationalization for ASP.NET](https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n#po-customization).

Features

- Localize everything: HTML, Razor, C#, VB, JavaScript, .NET attributes
  and data annotations, ...;
- SEO-friendly: language selection varies the URL, and Content-Language is set appropriately;
- Automatic: no URL/routing changes required in the app;
- High performance, minimal overhead and minimal heap allocations; Unit testing support;
- Smart: knows when to hold them, fold them, walk away, or run, based on i18n    best practices.

How I use i18n in the project step by step:

1. Add the I18N nuget package to your MVC project.
2. in Web.config:
3. Add a folder named "locale" to the root of your site. Create a subfolder for each culture you wish to support. For example, /locale/fr/.
4. copy i18n.PostBuild.exe into locale folder
5. Right click on tne project name --> Properties --> Build Events:
   in Post-build event command line:

"$(TargetDir)i18n.PostBuild.exe" "$(ProjectDir)\web.config"

7. In views use `[[[some text]]]` to translate it later
8. Build the project
9. Refresh Solution Explorer and push Show All Files
10. Include all files in "locale" folder into the project
11. Provide translation of the words in locale\fr\messages.po
12. In Global.aspx add :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //other app start code
        UrlLocalizer.UrlLocalizationScheme = UrlLocalizationScheme.Void;
    }
}
```

13. Create DefaultController :

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{   
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (Session["currentLanguage"] == null)
        {
            Session["currentLanguage"] = "en";
        }
     }    
}
```

14. In HomeController add inheritance of DefaultController and SwitchLanguage(string lang):

```
public class HomeController : DefaultController
{
    public HomeController() : base()
    { 
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SwitchLanguage(string lang)
        {
            LocalizedApplication.Current.DefaultLanguage = lang;
            Session["currentLanguage"] = lang;
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
        }
    }
}
```

15. In navigation bar View (_LoginPartial.cshtml in my case) add links to switch between languages:

```
        @if (Session["currentLanguage"].ToString() == "fr")
        {
            <li class="navItem">@Html.ActionLink("EN", "SwitchLanguage", "Home", new { lang = "en", area = "" }, null)</li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li class="navItem">@Html.ActionLink("FR", "SwitchLanguage", "Home", new { lang = "fr", area = "" }, null)</li>
        }
```

Build project, Start in Browser and enjoy!!!

see some help in:
https://www.codeday.top/2017/09/19/42409.html

Comment: I tried to use the currentLanguage session and is not working any clue